# Send push notification to APP without device token or register id

Tags: php, push-notification

I have already experienced to send push notifications to android and apple device with specific device token or registered id and I did use it in different projects, but this time I am just looking for a solution where I can send a push notification to APP means whoever installed the APP will get a notification.

Please let me know if this is possible and if yes then how.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need  push tokens to send notification and there is no option to send push message to all devices without knowing their token . But  you can send topic notifications if user has subscribed to that specific topic . You may need topic subscription to send push message to all subscribed users .
Client side you can subscribe to topic like

FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("TestTopic");

[find it here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging#:%7E:text=Based%20on%20the%20publish%2Fsubscribe,reliably%20to%20the%20right%20devices.)